# When are two space curves with same image equivalent?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, parametric, parametrization

Let $I_1, I_2$ are two non-degenerating intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ and, let $\gamma_j : I_j \to \mathbb{R}^n,\quad j=1,2$ be two parametrized [regular $\mathcal{C}^r$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_curve#Definitions)-curves with same trace (image in $\mathbb{R}^n$) $$\gamma_1(I_1)=\gamma_2(I_2).$$ What are the necessary and sufficient conditions that guarantee the existence of a $\mathcal{C}^r$-function $\varphi: I_1\to I_2$ such that

- $\varphi'(t)\neq 0$
- $\gamma_1(t)=\gamma_2(\varphi(t))$

for all $t\in I_1$ ?

I am trying to understand [this notion of equivalent curves.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_curve#Re-parametrization_and_equivalence_relation)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but of interest? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3211859/simple-closed-curves-have-the-same-trace-if-and-only-if-they-are-equivalent

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Thank you for the link.  If I got it correct, when the $\gamma_2$ is injective, it has a left inverse, and then we can take the $\varphi$ to be $\gamma_2^{-1}\gamma_1.$ Do you think injectivity is necessary for the existence of $\varphi$ ?

Comment: No, injectivity is not necessary. I'm not sure you'll find a satisfactory condition other than "there exists a reparametrization." The curves must have the same set of endpoints, and in a qualitative sense "must trace their images the same number of times (not including orientation)." <> It may help to think by example of the circle $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ over an arbitrary interval $[a, b]$.

Comment: Why do you expect that there is a non-tautological criterion for equivalence? As Andrew says, injective regular curves (ones with nowhere vanishing derivative) and same trace will be equivalent. This suffices for many purposes.